# set rows to zero except maximum value

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, max, zero

Hopefully someone can help me with the following MATLAB problem.
I have a matrix, for example:

a = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 6 5 ; 9 8 7 ]

I want to create a matrix with only the maximum of each row, and the rest set to zero.
So in this case:

amax = [ 0 0 3 ; 0 6 0 ; 9 0 0 ]

I figure this is not so dificult haha but I can't figure it out! 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Think logically about how you would go about finding the max in each row.  You need to loop through each item in the matrix, compare it to the previous max, and save the location if it is bigger.  Set the location of all but the largest to 0. Repeat for each row.  Go write some code.

Comment: I've got 'a(a<max(a)) = 0' for each row now and then I save each row.. It seems to work!

Comment: What programming language is it for? Is it pure mathematical question?  What have you tried so far? Downvote for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
amax = a .* bsxfun(@eq, a, max(a,[],2));
```

Comment: Wooow - this is perfect! But how did you figure the 'max(a,[],2)' part?! I want to understand, for next time..!